# What makes a field eligible for selecting data in a subreport?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report I'm trying to recreate from scratch after an update from VS2008 to VS2010 caused it to implode horribly.

I've gotten most of the way through, but I'm at a stage where I'm linking a field in the Main Report to a corresponding field in the Subreport.

I have set up a bunch of Database fields in the Subreport, I've added the table I want, TableA, I've linked it up as everything was linked in the original report, with TableA at the head of the linking chain, so that all the rows I want can be derived from the result of that first query ( **Actually, all of the links from the original Report were red in the Database Fields linking dialog, whereas mine are a bit rainbow-y. All the links in TableA are red, though... _** )

In the "Subreport Links" dialog, I have an integer which I know is being pulled from the database correctly. I've added it in the "Fields to link to" listbox, and selected the newly-created parameter in the "Subreport parameter to use" combobox. I've ticked the "Select data in subreport based on field" checkbox.

The database field I want to link to then does not appear in the second combobox.

Another integer field in TableA shows up fine in the "Select data..." combobox (and is linked to another field being passed in), so I don't know why these two integer fields, which are equally important, and exist on the same level, on the same table, are being treated differently by the report designed.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Alternatively, direct answers to the headline question are also welcome, I just added this explanation here for context.

Comment: Is the field that's not showing up a new field, ie. have you recently added it to the command (or table) have you restarted crystal reports?

Comment: Nope. This has been going on through numerous restarts and reboots and the like. Also, as mentioned, there's an older version of the form which shows the field, and that used to work fine, before something in CR2010 killed it. All problems are, as far as can be determined, due to my lack of knowledge of Crystal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I managed somewhat by chance to hack my way through to getting this working. I'll try and describe it as best I can.

I went back to the original, broken report and noticed that in Database Fields, the original report had a tick by that field, whereas my reconstruction did not.

I used the "Find In Formulas..." context menu command and ended up in the formula that is generated by the Subreport Links dialog.

Having found the function generated by the Subreport Links dialog, I decided that I didn't need the dialog anymore, and went back and edited the formula manually on my form, which then worked fine.

Feeling curious, I then went back to the Subreport Links dialog and found that *it* did not think the link had changed.

However, because the report now contains a reference to the field I wanted to link o, the Subreport Links dialog now displays the field... which is only actually referenced by the formula generated by the Subreport Links dialog. So it now only appears in the Subreport Links dialog because the Subreport Links formula references it...

Nicely circular logic by Crystal Reports, there.

Anyway, it works, and I've done my best to explain how and why I got it to work.

I'll leave this here in case it's of any use to anyone in the future.